# Adding class attribute from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, ajax

I have the following code:

`div1.Attributes.Add("class", "displayNone");`

it works on `page load` but doesn't on an `OnClick` event.

This is because my html `<div id="div1"></div>` seems to change to:

`<div id="div1_ucSomeControl_SoemthingElse"></div>`

after the page has been rendered.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that the ID of the control matters in this case. You may be running into this issue because the `class` attribute already exists. Try this instead:

```
div1.Attributes["class"] = "displayNone";
```

Comment: This actually worked, I am suprised this works over `div1.Attributes.Add("class", "displayNone"); ` Thanks :D!!

Comment: As I said, I believe you had this issue because the class attribute already existed, and you were adding another class attribute rather than updating the existing.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="div1" runat ="server">
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
</div>
```

code behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    div1.Attributes.Add("class", "displayNone");
}
```

this will be work.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should do this kind of attributes manupilation/addition in the Page_PreRender event:

```
div1.Attributes.Add("class", "displayNone");
```

anyway when you say it does not work in the OnClick event you still meant Server side I guess; because on client side you cannot execute that code in that way.

Server side, usage of the object by id like `div1` should always work, in codebehind objects's ids are not changed through the page life cycle.

Comment: hmmz I am doing it serverside by doing a partial postback using an update panel.